# Process readKey with high CPU load

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, cpu

I recently installed an "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" on a Raspberry 3 fully upgraded to evaluate some Z-Wave devices functionality. Now I see a high readKey load (15-20%) all around the clock which is not ok IMHO. What is it responsible for and is there a chance to get the reason of its running? The PPID is 1 by the way.

I can kill the process without losing any functionality which I am using.

Comment: The PPID is 1 because it is a service started by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), which is true of most or all background processes post-boot.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of z-way-server AFAIK. You may have installed it with the z-way installation script.

EDIT: take a look at /etc/init.d/readKey script for details.